# Why does negative numbers display like "5-" instead of "-5" in this simple calculator on HTML and javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm learning to code, this is just an exercise. any operation resulting in negative number will display wrong, but console.logs will display right.
why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
<style>

#calculator{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width:400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

#screen{
  width: 100%;  
  aspect-ratio: 4/1.5;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#input{
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);    
  color:white;
  font-size: 15vw;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#buttonsGrid{
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 4/5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color:white;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.singleButton{
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

[id="0Button"] {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

#equalButton, #plusButton, #minusButton, #xButton, #divisionButton{
 background-color: orange;
} 

#cButton, #negativePositiveButton, #percentageButton {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Simple calculator using JS</h1>

  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="screen">
      <input inputmode="numeric" id="input">
      </input>
    </div>

    <div id="buttonsGrid">
      <div id="cButton" class="singleButton">C
      </div>
      <div id="negativePositiveButton" class="singleButton">+/-
      </div>
      <div id="percentageButton" class="singleButton">%
      </div>
      <div id="divisionButton" class="singleButton">÷
      </div>

      <div id="7Button" class="singleButton numericButton">7</div>
      <div id="8Button" class="singleButton numericButton">8</div>
      <div id="9Button" class="singleButton numericButton">9</div>
      <div id="xButton" class="singleButton">x</div>

      <div id="4Button" class="singleButton numericButton">4</div>
      <div id="5Button" class="singleButton numericButton">5</div>
      <div id="6Button" class="singleButton numericButton">6</div>
      <div id="minusButton" class="singleButton">-</div>

      <div id="1Button" class="singleButton numericButton">1</div>
      <div id="2Button" class="singleButton numericButton">2</div>
      <div id="3Button" class="singleButton numericButton">3</div>
      <div id="plusButton" class="singleButton">+</div>

      <div id="0Button" class="singleButton numericButton">0</div>
      <div id="dotButton" class="singleButton numericButton">.</div>
      <div id="equalButton" class="singleButton">=</div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script >

      
  const inputScreen = document.getElementById('input');
  
  const cButton = document.getElementById('cButton');
  const MoodButton = document.getElementById('negativePositiveButton');
  const percentageButton = document.getElementById('percentageButton');
  
  const divisionButton = document.getElementById('divisionButton');
  const xButton = document.getElementById('xButton');
  const minusButton = document.getElementById('minusButton');
  const plusButton = document.getElementById('plusButton');
  const equalButton = document.getElementById('equalButton');
  
  
  
  const numericButtonArr = [...document.getElementsByClassName('numericButton')];
  const operationButtonArr = [xButton, minusButton, plusButton];
  
  //button's events
  cButton.addEventListener('click', clearData);
  numericButtonArr.forEach(numericButton => {
    numericButton.addEventListener('click', displayNumbers);
  });
  operationButtonArr.forEach(operationButton => {
    operationButton.addEventListener('click', clearForSecondNumber);
  });
  divisionButton.addEventListener('click', handleDivision);
  MoodButton.addEventListener('click', changeMood);
  percentageButton.addEventListener('click', calculatePercentage);
  equalButton.addEventListener('click', performOperation);
  
  //variables
  let currentNumber = 0;
  let firstNumber = 0;
  let selectedOperation = '';
  let displayValue = '';
  
  let secondNumber = '';
  
  //Clear all data for C button press
  function clearData() {
    inputScreen.value = '';
    currentNumber = 0;
    displayValue = '';
    firstNumber = 0;
    selectedOperation = '';
  }
  
  //display numeric and dot buttons press on display
  function displayNumbers() {
    const value = this.textContent;
  
    if (value === '.') {
      // preventing dot duplication
      if (!displayValue.includes('.')) {
        displayValue += value;
        inputScreen.value = displayValue;
      }
    } else {
        displayValue += value;
        inputScreen.value = displayValue;
    }
  
    currentNumber = parseFloat(displayValue);
  }
  
  //convert - to + and + to-
  function changeMood(){
    currentNumber = currentNumber * (-1); 
    displayValue = currentNumber;
    inputScreen.value = displayValue;
  }
  
  //Calculate %
  function calculatePercentage(){
    currentNumber = currentNumber / (100);  
    displayValue = currentNumber;
    inputScreen.value = displayValue;
  }
  
  //for +,- and x. for division didnt work here :(
  function clearForSecondNumber() {
    selectedOperation = this.textContent;
    inputScreen.value = '';
    displayValue = '';
    firstNumber = currentNumber;
  }
  
  
  // Function to handle the division operation
  function handleDivision() {
    selectedOperation = '/';
    inputScreen.value = '';
    displayValue = '';
    firstNumber = currentNumber;
  }
  
  function performOperation() {
    secondNumber = currentNumber;
    let result;
  
    if (selectedOperation === 'x') {
      result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    } else if (selectedOperation === '/') {
      result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    } else if (selectedOperation === '-') {
      result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    } else if (selectedOperation === '+') {
      result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
  
    inputScreen.value = result;
    currentNumber = result;
    firstNumber = result;
    displayValue = '';
  }
  
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you set the writing direction to RTL (right-to-left) by setting `direction: rtl;`. This makes sense for languages like Arabic.

Perhaps you wanted to simply right-align the text (without reversing its direction), in this case you need `text-align: right;`.

Comment: Thank you for your time! This was my first dumb question, hurray!

Comment: Even though text-align: right; didn't work, justify-content: flex-end; did. These kinds of rules are driving me crazy. I guess I'll know which works when with some practice.